# after i enter python project3.py in Anaconda Powershell Prompt (anaconda3)

Tags: python, powershell, anaconda, prompt, anaconda3

```
import gradio as gr
import openai, subprocess
openai.api_key = "sk-PFIsH04TaCgUrbnjnnlkT3BlbkFJ9FmjONClKC"
messages = [{"role": "system", "content": 'You are a master of dressing, and no clothing problem can trouble you.'}]
def transcribe(audio):
    global messages

    audio_file = open(audio, "rb")
    transcript = openai.Audio.transcribe("whisper-1", audio_file)

    messages.append({"role": "user", "content": transcript["text"]})

    response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(model="ft:gpt-3.5-turbo", messages=messages)

    system_message = response["choices"][0]["message"]
    messages.append(system_message)

    subprocess.call(["wsay", system_message['content']])

    chat_transcript = ""
    for message in messages:
        if message['role'] != 'system':
            chat_transcript += message['role'] + ": " + message['content'] + "\n\n"

    return chat_transcript

ui = gr.Interface(fn=transcribe, inputs=gr.Audio(source="microphone", type="filepath"), outputs="text").launch()
ui.launch()
```

Error:

```
(base) PS C:\Users\user\Downloads\yolov7-main\yolov7-main> python project3.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Downloads\yolov7-main\yolov7-main\project3.py", line 30, in <module>
    ui = gr.Interface(fn=transcribe, inputs=gr.Audio(source="microphone"), outputs="text").launch()
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gradio\component_meta.py", line 146, in wrapper
    return fn(self, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'source'
```

can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

It's a typo, should be `sources` instead of `source`. The error message has already told you that the `gr.Audio` don't have keyword parameter `source`. Here is the document of Audio component: https://www.gradio.app/docs/audio